# Java access object from other method

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm trying to make a button that changes the color when you click it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class buttonPrototype extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
public buttonPrototype() {
    boolean READY = false;
    ...
    JButton ready = new JButton("READY");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 6;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        p.add(ready, c);
    ...
    ready.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("READY".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        if (READY == true) {
            READY = false;
            ready.setIcon("images/notready.png");
        } else {
            READY = true;
            ready.setIcon("images/ready.png");
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, I am not able to get the setIcon() to work because the ready object is in another method. I have read some online tutorials but still do not get how to reference this object in a second class. How do I do this?

Comment: `JButton ready ;
public buttonPrototype() {
   
   ready=  new JButton("READY");` ??

Answer (score 0):

In your case I see two easy solutions: You should use one of them, not both.

First:

```
JButton ready = new JButton("READY");
```

should be a member variable, so you can access it within the listener by simply call it:

```
ready.setIcon("images/ready.png");
```

OR

Your method is passed an event. You can obtain the source (which is actually the button) by calling:

```
((JButton)e.getSource).setIcon("images/ready.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the ready variable out of the method (as class variable), like this:

```java
public class buttonPrototype extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    boolean READY;
    JButton ready;

    public buttonPrototype() {
        READY = false;
        ...
        ready = new JButton("READY");
        ...
        ready.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think buttonPrototype is constructor that call in the class creation